# Starting X with Cywgin

Tags: cygwin, windows-10, xserver

Running latest Cygwin64, Window 10, `startxwin` gives:

```
winClipboardProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.
winMultiWindowXMsgProcErrorHandler - ERROR: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
```

and then hangs. Any clues?

Comment: I have a bunch of those messages in the log (a new appears when another window opens) but everything seems to work fine. I mean that the cause for the hangs might be something else. Not that it is going to help you but still.

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work for me

```
xinit -- -multiwindow -clipboard
```

Comment: kindly please explain little more

Comment: @un-lucky I found it on another cygwin question on stackoverflow it is also on the cygwin email listings.  Does it work for you?  I'm not sure where the original question is now.

Comment: It worked for me. I had to force kill a xterm session and had this problem of OP ever since. Many thanks!

Comment: @daaxix I'm not running Windows 8.1.  My recommendation would be to just upgrade to W10 and use the built in Windows Subsystems For Linux.